# Multiple joins with conditions in rails 3.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am stuck again with a simple query. I have the following models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :items, :through => :item_types, :source => :category    
end

class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :items 
end

class Item
  belongs_to :item_type
end
```

Now I am trying to write a query that fetches all the items that fall under a category. I've written a query like this:

```
Category.joins(:item_types,:items).where("category.id=?",1)
```

Its throwing me an error when where condition is included. I have no clue why it does that.I thought this is a very basic join i could do it myself but in vain.

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Answer (score 2):

```
Category.joins(:item_types, :items).where(:item_type => {:category_id => 1})
```

Comment: my items table does not have a category_id column

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler if you want to build many-to-many association with ActiveRecord.
If I clearly understand your question you should do something like this

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :items, :through => :item_types
end

# app/models/item_type.rb
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :item
end

# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :categories, :through => :item_types
end

# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @category_items = @category.items
end
```

Comment: nick am getting the item_types when i query using @category.items.the resulting query is like this:               SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "item_types" ON "categories
"."id" = "item_types"."category_id" WHERE "item_types"."category_id" = 1

Comment: you completely changed my requirement.I have three models:Category,ItemType and Item.A Category can have many itemtypes and many items through itemtype.A ItemType belongs to a category and has many items.An Item belongs to a ItemType ..this is what i modelled in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Category.joins(:item_types,:items).where("**categories**.id=?",1)
```

table name for category should be in where clause